# Typescript Function Type - Make the second param type depends on the first param type

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have a function `func(arg1, arg2)`

`arg1`'s type is a union of constants, e.g. `type Arg1 = 'a' | 'b' | 'c'` and `arg2`'s type is based on `arg1`.

If `arg1` is `a` or `b`, `arg2` should be `string`. If `arg2` is `c`, `arg2` should be `string[]`.

I wonder if how I can accomplish this in typescript? Thanks

I try to do the following but it gives the error "Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'" and typescript wasn't able to type narrow for some reasons

```ts
type Arg1 = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

const expectString = (str:string) => {}

const func= <T extends Arg1>(arg1: T, arg2: T extends "c" ? string[] : string) => {
    if (arg1 === 'a'){
        expectString(arg2) //This gives the error "Argument of type 'string | string[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'."
    }     
}
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NdEYYm) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. You the boss. I made a slight enhancement by adding `type Arg1 = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';` and using `Exclude` `type Args = [arg1: Exclude<Arg1, "c">, arg2: string] | [arg1: "c", arg2: string[]];` - [new link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=2&ssc=84&pln=2&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwIxQLxQOQEMNQD6YBGuBGAxhgNwBQoksiAzmlANpaJIBcUAogB5kANgFcAJhAA88ZABooAIjIKAfPI4IATD0bA4ASwB2CALr42G7ouXrE2qLoPHWJkzWpkA9od1QI-SDJgAGU9IwQWAApHHTDjAEo0FSgAbygAX2oPb18AMxFDMiiAOlL2TlstEx4ZRkTUZJTqKCh9XKhIyzRUdGwMRKaWlv9AkLiETrt45ozqTOogA). I tried this way before but didn't work. This is very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define function overloads at the expense of diminished type-safety inside the implementation.

```
const expectString = (str:string) => {}

function func(arg1 : 'a' | 'b', arg2: string): any;
function func(arg1 : 'c', arg2: string[]): any;
function func (arg1: 'a' | 'b' | 'c', arg2: any) {
  if (arg1 === 'a'){
      expectString(arg2);
  }     
}

func('a', 'my string');
func('c', ['my string array']);
```

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBApgDwA52FAylATgSzAcxgF4YAKaLALgr3wEpiA+GAbwF8AoDgMwFcw0OcDD4DSAQyz4AjDEowA5OIUwAPooBGCgDQxJ+AEzyaBOvPFgAngG4e-QcNHAJU2fIXAdeqUZgn8ANoAumZ6VrZOUEJgIvZk+tLuymqaKuoeXvq+FpYMLBwwMDjc8a7ERCRKCnT5hXXwyKgY2LQuhnS2hWz1MBycdmJVugoAtpZ+LQTVEfakGboBo+P+3ljilgohtkA)

Comment: Thanks so much for your help Anton! Sorry for my delay in getting back. Is there a way to not diminished type-safety inside the implementation?

Comment: @Xitang the comment under your post has a working example which is fully type-safe.

Comment: You the boss Anton. It works. I made a slight enhancement to it by adding `type Arg1 = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';` and using Exclude `type Args = [arg1: Exclude<Arg1, "c">, arg2: string] | [arg1: "c", arg2: string[]];` - [new link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTgcwIxQLxQOQEMNQD6YBGuBGAxhgNwBQoksiAzmlANpaJIBcUAogB5kANgFcAJhAA88ZABooAIjIKAfPI4IATD0bA4ASwB2CALr42G7ouXrE2qLoPHWJkzWpkA9od1QI-SDJgAGU9IwQWAApHHTDjAEo0FSgAbygAX2oPb18AMxFDMiiAOlL2TlstEx4ZRkTUZJTqKCh9XKhIyzRUdGwMRKaWlv9AkLiETrt45ozqTOogA). I tried to do it this way before but didn't get it to work. This is very helpful!